# Configuring a vpn connection with network manager

Tags: network-manager, vpn

I'm on Xubuntu and I just want to make a simple modification in the configuration of the network-manager for the openvpn connection, and it requires me to authenticate. Here is what is going on : I go in the network-manager applet, I click on "vpn", then "modify", then I uncheck the box "connect automatically", but I can't click on apply, and when I hover the mouse over the "apply" button it says I should authenticate. More importantly the vpn connection works when I first set it up, but as soon as I restart the computer, my vpn connection fails and I am unable to make modifications to the configuration of the vpn in gnome network-manager.

Comment: Don't you over complicate things? Why not just type in the password to authenticate?

Comment: It doesn't ask directly for a password, it's the message I get when I hover the mouse over the "apply" button and I can't click on it...

Comment: That usually means that the network Manager doesn't know how to deal with the supplied info - might be an 'illegal' character or unexpected space somewhere. By the way, it runs as root by default.

Comment: I go in the network-manager applet, I click on "vpn", then "modify", then I uncheck the box "connect automatically", but I can't click on apply, and when I hover the mouse over the "apply" button it says I should authenticate.

Comment: You might want to add that info to the question, to make it clearer.

Comment: It's done. Now it's clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I found what was keeping me from performing the modifications and probably also why the connection would fail after reboot. When I imported the configuration file, I had to uncheck the option to set it for "all users", which is enabled by default. Now vpn works and I can make modifications.